# Parsing String Mixed with HTML, Words, Numbers, and Dates

Tags: vba

I need to extract unique words and numeric values from a string. At this point I have a function that strips out everything and returns only alphanumeric words. I need to also recognize when a word is really a date or a number and prevent the text from being split apart. How can I do this?

Here is the splitter function I currently have:

```
Public Function GetAlphaNumericWords(ByVal InputText As String) As Collection
' This function splits the rich text input into unique alpha-numeric only strings
    Dim words() As String
    Dim characters() As Byte
    Dim text As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set GetAlphaNumericWords = New Collection

    text = Trim(PlainText(InputText))
    If Len(text) > 0 Then
    ' Replace any non alphanumeric characters with a space
        characters = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)
        For i = LBound(characters) To UBound(characters)
            If Not (Chr(characters(i)) Like "[A-Za-z0-9 ]") Then
                characters(i) = 32 ' Space character
            End If
        Next
        ' Merge the byte array back to a string and then split on spaces
        words = VBA.Split(StrConv(characters, vbUnicode))

        ' Add each unique word to the output collection
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each text In words
            If (text <> vbNullString) Then GetAlphaNumericWords.Add CStr(text), CStr(text)
            If Err Then Err.Clear
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

An example of the output this function currently returns:

```
GetAlphaNumericWords("Hello World!  Test 1. 123.45 8/22/2013 August 22, 2013")

Hello
World
Test
1
123
45
8
22
2013
August
```

What I really want is:

```
Hello
World
Test
1
123.45
8/22/2013
```

Comment: I have considered creating a buffer that adds a character. If the buffer's contents are numeric, then continue  to add the next character. If the buffer no longer is numeric after adding the next character, then add the buffer as a word to the collection. This would capture numbers, but dates would still not be added. Maybe a second date specific buffer that ignores up to two special characters between numeric text? Then if the value can be converted to a date, the whole string is added as a single word. Seems plausible, but I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a lot of work when you could use regular expressions.  See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for a good starting point.

If you add a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" and add the following functions (I've included a few more functions than necessary, in case they're useful elsewhere):

```
Public Function RegEx(strInput As String, strRegEx As String, Optional bIgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional bMultiLine As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim RegExp As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set RegExp = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    With RegExp
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = strRegEx
    End With
    RegEx = RegExp.test(strInput)
    Set RegExp = Nothing
End Function

Public Function RegExMatch(strInput As String, strRegEx As String, Optional MatchNo As Long = 0, Optional FirstIDX As Long, Optional Lgth As Long, Optional bIgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional bMultiLine As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim RegExp As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Set RegExp = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    With RegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = strRegEx
    End With
    If RegExp.test(strInput) Then
        Set Matches = RegExp.Execute(strInput)
        If MatchNo > Matches.Count - 1 Then
            RegExMatch = ""
        Else
            RegExMatch = Matches(MatchNo).value
            FirstIDX = Matches(MatchNo).FirstIndex
            Lgth = Matches(MatchNo).Length
        End If
    Else
        RegExMatch = ""
    End If
    Set RegExp = Nothing
End Function

Public Function RegexMatches(strInput As String, strRegEx As String, Optional bIgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional bMultiLine As Boolean = False) As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Dim RegExp As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set RegExp = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    With RegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = strRegEx
    End With
    Set RegexMatches = RegExp.Execute(strInput)
    Set RegExp = Nothing
End Function

Public Function RegExReplace(strInput As String, strRegEx As String, strReplace As String, Optional bGlobal As Boolean = True, Optional bIgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional bMultiLine As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim RegExp As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set RegExp = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    With RegExp
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = strRegEx
        .Global = bGlobal
    End With
    RegExReplace = RegExp.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
    Set RegExp = Nothing
End Function
```

You should be able to use them to make a far more useful and elegant solution.

You should consider a regex pattern similar to the following:

```
\b(\w+)\b
```

and code similar to the following - for each match & submatch using `RegexMatches`, try a `CDec` and a `CDate` on it, and reject it if you *don't* get an error (the absence of an error would indicate a legitimate date or number):

```
Dim Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
...
Set Matches = RegexMatches(InputText , "\b(\w+)\b")
                If Matches.Count > 0 Then
                    For CtrA = 0 To Matches.Count - 1
                        For CtrB = 0 To Matches(CtrA).SubMatches.Count - 1
                            On Error Resume Next
                            TestVariant = Null
                            TestVariant = CDec(Matches(CtrA).Submatches(CtrB))
                            TestVariant = CDate(Matches(CtrA).Submatches(CtrB))
                            On Error Goto 0
                            If IsNull(TestVariant) Then
                                ' Do further processing to check if the submatch can be split on non-alphanumeric characters... 
                            Else
                                GetAlphaNumericWords.Add Matches(CtrA).Submatches(CtrB), Matches(CtrA).Submatches(CtrB)
                            End If
                        Next
                    Next
                End If
```

Comment: I only ever knew about regular expressions for the `Like` operator. This is great! Thank you.