# Find specific text in a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IFERROR(MID(I46,FIND("-",I46,8)-2,5),"")
```

I have a vast string of information copied into one cell from another program. There are several parts of this string that mean absolutely nothing for my current purpose. I want to extract the relevant information, it is always formatted the same way, but not always in the same position within the string. I am working with the above code which returns what I'm looking for, but also other variations when "-" is found, which can be often.

The information I want to extract will always be LetterLetter-NumberNumber, ex: AA-01 AA-02 AB-01, and so on, always 5 characters.

How can I extract just this?

Then, in another row if need be, I want to remove duplicate instances (there will nearly always be duplicates).

What I get now is;

```
HA-03
HA-03
T - S
Y - R
HA-03
HA-03
HA-03
HA-03

Y - R
HA-06
HA-06

R - S
HA-07

HA-09
HA-09
HA-09
```

First, I'd like to just get;

```
HA-03
HA-03
HA-03
HA-03
HA-03
HA-03
HA-06
HA-06
HA-07
HA-09
HA-09
HA-09
```

Then convert that into;

```
HA-03
HA-06
HA-07
HA-09
```

If there is a way to skip the middle-man, I'm all ears =)

Thank You.

Comment: can you give a small list of your initial data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a macro using `Range.RemoveDuplicates` to de-duplicate your list and then `Like` or regular expressions (see the code I posted in [Parsing String Mixed with HTML, Words, Numbers, and Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390434/parsing-string-mixed-with-html-words-numbers-and-dates/18393082#18393082)) in a loop over the remaining cells to check if cells meet your criteria and delete those that do not match.

De-duplicating then matching would probably be a bit more efficient, but you could do it either way around.

If you're new to VBA and want some code, add a comment and I'll post some.

**EDIT:**

You'll need to go to the Visual Basic editor (Alt-F11), select menu item Tools/References...,  find and check "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5", then click OK.  Then in the project explorer (Ctrl- R), right-click on the `VBA Project` for your workbook and `Insert` > `Module`.

Add the following code:

```
Public Function RegEx(strInput As String, strRegEx As String, Optional bIgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional bMultiLine As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim RegExp As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set RegExp = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    With RegExp
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = strRegEx
    End With
    RegEx = RegExp.test(strInput)
    Set RegExp = Nothing
End Function
```

(You can add the other Regular Expression code from [Parsing String Mixed with HTML, Words, Numbers, and Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390434/parsing-string-mixed-with-html-words-numbers-and-dates/18393082#18393082) if you think you might use it later)

Add the following code (Assuming that the data that you want to delete is in Column A):

```
Public Sub DedupeAndFilter()
    Dim RCtr As Long
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    For RCtr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Rows(RCtr).Text = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Rows(RCtr).Delete xlShiftUp
        ElseIf Not RegEx(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Rows(RCtr), "[A-Z]{2}-\d\d", True) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Rows(RCtr).Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

then, with the cursor in the `DedupeAndFilter` code block, press `F5` or click the green Run ">" triangle.  The code will then remove duplicates, blank cells and non-conforming cells from Column A.

If you want to change the column affected, change "A:A" in `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")` to any other column reference, or substitute `Activesheet.Selection` and select the column you want.

Comment: I can't even spell VBA :) If there isn't a way to do this with a formula, and we can skip a few steps along the way, I'm willing to learn. I would much appreciate the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid VBA, then try this:

```
Column A
asdfHA-03asdfasdf
HA-03sadfsa
asdfT - S
Y - Rasdfsad
asdfHA-03adf
asdHA-04
asdfsadf
```

Then on use this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)-2,5),""))),IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)-2,5),""),"")
```

This should exclude the ones with `spaces`, then you can just copy paste as values, and [Remove Duplicates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx#BMremove_duplicate_values)