# Copy text from a string if that same string contains specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have something similar to the following string in one cell;

```
Thingy AA-03 1 5a5a5555555aaa bbbb000001111111 02/05/2013 ONE 1 EA HANDLE 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.0 0.0 0.000 0.0 F2AA 0.0000000
```

I would like to return bb000001111111, but only if the cell contains AA-03 somewhere in it, the position of the desired return and the *find if* are fluid.

The return will change, but will always be formatted the same, two letters, 5 0's, then the identifying information, a 6-8 digit number, with no spaces.  bb000001234567

Is this possible with just a formula?

Thanks.

I'm extremely close with;

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("HA-03",IFERROR(MID(Data!I47,FIND("F2AA00000",Data!I46),7),Data!I46))),IFERROR(MID(Data!I46,FIND("F2AA00000",Data!I46),16),""),"")
```

Comment: When you say the position is 'fluid' do you mean by starting character, or by position of the word? Excel formulas are very bad at matching regular expressions (to try to find what you want in the string), especially if there will be other words that may trip it up (are you sure there are never two strings with matching patterns?)

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be a continuation of [Find specific text in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840019/find-specific-text-in-a-string)...

You can use a VBA function as a worksheet function.

If you add the following code to the code you added from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840235/1687613):

```
Public Function RegExMatch(strInput As String, strRegEx As String, Optional MatchNo As Long = 0, Optional FirstIDX As Long, Optional Lgth As Long, Optional bIgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional bMultiLine As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim RegExp As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Set RegExp = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    With RegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = strRegEx
    End With
    If RegExp.test(strInput) Then
        Set Matches = RegExp.Execute(strInput)
        If MatchNo > Matches.Count - 1 Then
            RegExMatch = ""
        Else
            RegExMatch = Matches(MatchNo).value
            FirstIDX = Matches(MatchNo).FirstIndex
            Lgth = Matches(MatchNo).Length
        End If
    Else
        RegExMatch = ""
    End If
    Set RegExp = Nothing
End Function
```

...You can then have a formula:

```
=IF(RegEx(A1,"[A-Z]{2}-\d\d"), RegExMatch(A1,"[A-Z]{2}0{5}\d{6,8}"),"")
```

You might want to look at the Reference section [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for a lot more useful information on regular expressions.